# Get row in Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I am trying to use code below but it is not working because of the `ItemContainerGenerator`

```
  var selectedRow = (DataGridRow)myGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myGrid.SelectedItem);
```

[Is this only one solution?](http://silverlightips.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/get-datagrid-selectedrow-in-silverlight/)

How to fix it?

Comment: So you are stating that "the `ItemContainerGenerator` is the reason" you are not using the given line of code to retrieve the selected row. But you are not stating why it is the reason. The question -as it is now- is of no help to anyone who if having the same problem and searches SO for an answer. Please edit your question to be "complete" in that regard. And please add a short description of the linked solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pick it from the `visual tree`, the `DataGrid` offers no convenient access.

```
var selectedRow = myGrid.GetVisualDescendants()
                        .OfType<DataGridRow>()
                        .Where( row => row.DataContext == myGrid.SelectedItem)
                        .SingleOrDefault();
```

I recommend you write an extension method for this, it will enhance the code's readability and you can reuse it easily.